# How to use foreach() to display results from array

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following query:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE status = 1");
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sth->execute();

$reviews = array();

while($row = $sth->fetch()){    
    $reviews[]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $reviews[]['comment'] = $row['comment'];
    $reviews[]['star'] = $row['star'];
}

return $reviews;
}
```

Which returns the following for `var_dump($this->reviews)`:

```
array(9) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(5) "name1" } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["comment"]=> string(8) "comment1" } 
[2]=> array(1) { ["star"]=> string(1) "4" } 
[3]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(5) "name2" } 
[4]=> array(1) { ["comment"]=> string(8) "comment2" } 
[5]=> array(1) { ["star"]=> string(1) "4" } 
[6]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(5) "name3" } 
[7]=> array(1) { ["comment"]=> string(8) "comment3" } 
[8]=> array(1) { ["star"]=> string(1) "4" } 
}
```

How can I use `foreach` to display `name`, `comment`, `star` by row?

I.e.:

```
name1, email1@email.com, comment1
name2, email2@email.com, comment2
name3, email3@email.com, comment3
```

I know it should be something like:

```
foreach( $this->reviews as $key){
  echo "Name:". $this->reviews['name'] . "Email:" . $this->reviews['email'] . "Comment:" .  $this->reviews['comment'];
}
```

But this gives me `Notice: Undefined index: name`. How do I define the index?

Comment: Instead of $this->reviews use $key inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach( $this->reviews as $value){
  echo "Name:". $value['name'] . "Email:" . $value['email'] . "Comment:" .  $value['comment'];
}
```

Notice how i use `$value` instead of `$this->reviews` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate an array of arrays. Something like

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()){    
    $reviews[] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'comment' => $row['comment'], 'star'=> $row['star']);
}
```

Now your `$reviews` object will have just as many elements as there were rows in the query result, and you can print it any way you want.

As for printing (which I think is where your error message is coming from):

```
foreach($reviews as $thisValue) {
  echo "Name: ". $value['name'];
}
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks, I still have an Notice: Undefined index: name, is my foreach function correct?

Comment: @alias51 that is strange. Try putting a `print_r($row);` inside the loop - what do you see? Is the error during the creation of the array or during the printing?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting up the insert into the array incorrectly:

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()){    
    $reviews[]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $reviews[]['comment'] = $row['comment'];
    $reviews[]['star'] = $row['star'];
}
```

The shorthand `[]` inserts a new element each and every single time, you want to actually insert an array AS the element.

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()){    
    $revArr=array('name' => $row['name'], 'comment' => $row['comment'], 'star' => $row['star']);
    $reviews[]=$revArr;
}
```

Edit: Now change your second foreach to this:

```
foreach( $this->reviews as $key){
  echo "Name:". $key['name'] . "Email:" . $key['email'] . "Comment:" .  $key['comment'];
}
```

Comment: @Floris But I had a more and complete answer? :P Besides, it was less than a minute apart and I typed a lot :)

Comment: Thanks, I still have an `Notice: Undefined index: name`, is my `foreach` function correct?

Comment: @fluffeh - oh OK it's a draw

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $this->reviews as $key){
  echo "Name:". $this->reviews['name'] . "Email:" . $this->reviews['email'] . "Comment:" .  $this->reviews['comment'];
}
```

this is not the right way, because now you are working on $key so write -

```
   foreach( $this->reviews as $key){
      echo "Name:". $key['name'] . "Email:" . $key['email'] . "Comment:" .  $key['comment'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follow:

```
$reviews = array();
while($row = $sth->fetch()){    
   $reviews[] = array($row['name'], $row['comment'], $row['email'], $row['star']);
}
```

and then you can do a heredoc:

```
$str = '';
foreach( $this->reviews as $review ){
   $str .=<<<html
       name: {$review['name']}
       email: {$review['email']}
       comment: {$review['comment']}
       start: {$review['star']}
   html;
}
```

finally i echo everything:

```
echo $str;
```

I think this is much cleaner, and you can add any html.